# Nginx proxy to Nginx Wordpress servers using different server names

Tags: wordpress, nginx, proxy

I have an Nginx proxy server that proxy passes to a variety of backend servers. I have been asked to set up a proxy pass to an Nginx WordPress server that I have no control over.

The issue is: the URL that we're listening on is www.customerdomain.com, but the WordPress server listens on someinternaldomain.host.com.

Is there a way to pass a different host header to the WordPress server without screwing up the www.customerdomain.com in the browser address bar?

My sample config below:

```
server {
  listen       *:443 ssl;

  server_name  www.customerdomain.com;

  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/somecert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/somecert.key;
  include includes/ssl.conf;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;


  location / {

    proxy_pass          https://wordpress-upstream;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_connect_timeout  90;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  }

}
```

Comment: proxy_set_header Host someinternaldomain.host.com;

Comment: Yeah, tried that, but it seems to be redirecting. Actually going to close this question, since I think the issue of the redirect is sitting on the client's end not ours.